# Aggregate the total revenue for each date by using aggregate function

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, tapply

I have a daily revenue dataset `df` from `2016-01-01` to `2017-05-21`. The dataset contains `Datum`, `languages` and `Opbrengst` variables.

```
       Datum    lanuage  Opbrengst
596    20160101  bg       254
923    20160101  bg-bg    434
1044   20160101  ca       115
1544   20160101  ca-es    238
2008   20160101  cs       251
....
```

I want to `group by Datum` for the `Opbrengst`.

I've tried the method from [How to sum a variable by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

```
 aggregate(Datum ~ Opbrengst, data=df, FUN="sum")
```

or

```
 tapply(df$Datum, df$Opbrengst, FUN=sum)
```

The results become

```
       Opbrengst     Datum
1             10   786304986
2            100  1048457710
3           1000   221796843
4        1000,01    20160628
5        1000,78    20170104
```

This is not the result I want. I want to have **the sum of the revenue of each date**. I am wondering where is the problem?

Comment: Did you meant `aggregate(Opbrengst~Datum, df1, sum)`

Comment: It doesn't matter how quick you type, @akrun is always there first... :-)

Comment: @akrun I've tried `aggregate(Opbrengst~Datum, df, sum)` but it shows `Error in Summary.factor(c(5646L, 9263L, 647L, 5198L, 5556L, 384L, 7080L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: @Sheryl It means your Opbrengst column is not numeric as we assumed.  Do you have `,` etc in `Opbrengst`?  In that `df$Opbrengst <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$Opbrengst))` and then apply the code

Comment: @akrun, Thanks a lot! The problem solved! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two problems.

1) the use of grouping variable in the formula method of `aggregate`.  The grouping variable is placed at the rhs of `~` while the variable of interest `Opbrengst` on the `lhs`

```
aggregate(Opbrengst~Datum, df1, sum)
```

2) The column 'Opbrengst' is `factor`.  It seems to have `,` character and that result in `factor` class while reading (if we don't specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv/read.table` etc.).  One option is to remove the `,` with `sub`, convert to `numeric` and then use `aggregate`

```
df$Opbrengst <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$Opbrengst))
```